# Drupal vs CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, drupal

I have been using CodeIgniter all these while, and have solid foundation in OOP languages like Java/Python/PHP. However, I am being forced to switch to Drupal, but I have not have any experience in that, neither do I have any experience working with any CMS.

I understand that Drupal is a Content Management System, and CodeIgniter is a PHP framework, and I have been wondering what are the solid differences between these 2.

1.If Drupal is a Content Management System, does that mean that most of the Drupal modules comes with an interface like wordpress, which allows you to fiddle around a pre-defined set of rules, limited customisation on backend/frontend?

2.To what extent are customisation(if any) available? Would it be required to go through a load of files to change a certain function?

3.Would I need to have a solid programming base to use Drupal?

4.Is it possible to insert Drupal modules as libraries into CodeIgniter? I am aware of [Ignite Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/1247682), but I have not tried it yet.

If anyone could share any knowledge on this area, anything I would need to know on the differences between these 2 would be great.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really an opinion forum, it's a question and answer opportunity.

Comment: I was hoping for some answers actually. I wasn't aware that this would be classified as an opinion forum. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: One's a CMS and the other is a framework.  They're not really comparable.

Comment: Drupal is what it is. Is a purpose-built *content management system*. It's tools are designed to accomplish those tasks. Is it like WordPress? I don't think so, but it's not swimming-in-the-ocean broad either. You don't have to be a professional programmer to work with it. You don't really have to be a solid programmer to work with what it gives plugin developers. I think you're fine, it's just different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal is CMS/CMF, look at api.drupal.org. [Drupal and OOP](http://drupal.org/node/547518) - this article about OOP interactions.

1. Modules are greatly customizable via hooks. Of course, there's can be modules that hard-coded, since it's written by open-source community.
2. You shouldn't change Drupal core or contributed modules code, act via hooks (in your custom modules and themes).
3. Yes, it's recommend.